# Reassign a pandas df field to 'both' when the record contains both values

Tags: python, pandas

In the pandas dataframe there are 3 columns including RiderID and Type. Types can be either A or B.
The data looks like:

```
RiderID  Type  AnotherCol
1        A     some information
2        B     some information
2        B     some information
3        A     some information
3        B     some information
```

So rider 3 has both 2 types. i want to reassign the last 2 records' Type to 'both'

```
RiderID  Type  AnotherCol
1        A     some information
2        B     some information
2        B     some information
3        Both     some information
3        Both     some information
```

I can only think out to get a dataframe containing all RiderID that have 2 Types by:

```
temp = data.groupby(by='RiderID')[['Type']].nunique()
temp = temp[temp['Type'] ==2].reset_index()
```

and temp right joins with the original dataframe 'data' using RiderID. (then some filtering and field removal).

But I feel there must be a less complicated way to do it.

Comment: Do you only have A/B types or can generalize to any number of types?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df.groupby('RiderID')['Type'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

df.loc[m, 'Type'] = 'Both'
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
   RiderID  Type        AnotherCol
0        1     A  some information
1        2     B  some information
2        2     B  some information
3        3  Both  some information
4        3  Both  some information
```

If you only have 2 Types, you can also use:

```
g = df['Type'].eq('A').groupby(df['RiderID'])

# if we have an A are there also non-A in the group?
m = g.transform('any') != g.transform('all')

df.loc[m, 'Type'] = 'Both'
```